# Leaflet.js with a non real world map! Coordinates

Tags: javascript, mapping, leaflet

I'm working on creating a map of Day Z (the game) with leaflet JS and want 
to be able to plot items on the map using the in game coordinate system see 
http://dayz.ollieb.net

In game the top left coordinate is 000 000, then 001, 001 where units of 10 represent a grid so 010, 010 would be the top left "grid" (similar to ordinance survey).

How do I create a method to convert the provided coordinate systems (either 
points or latlong) to work on this way. Basically they just need to go from 
000, 000 (top left) to 145, 130 (bottom right). Currently I am having 
trouble using lat/long as it curves to compensate for the projection and 
points (x/y) seem to change per computer!

How can I take an in game point and create a marker on the map at that 
point? Presumably I need to tell Leaflet.js what "number" the top left and 
bottom right of the map are somehow?

Sorry for the lack of understanding, I have read through all the docs and 
can't see anything like this mentioned!

See an example here: 
http://dabrothas.net/sei/daisy/index.asp?mode=mark&z=3&x=-109.2294921875&y=73.49222029152183

Comment: The website http://dabrothas.net/sei/daisy/index.asp?mode=mark&z=3&x=-109.2294921875&y=73.49222029152183 now redirects to my little pony...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm Leaflet author.

Check out the following issues for code examples on setting up a non-world CRS: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/210 
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/676

I plan to do some refactoring of projection logic for 0.4 release to make such things much easier and more natural, so stay tuned!

Comment: Links are outdated! Did you figure out how to use Leaflet with a basic tile coordinate system? I don't want to use longitude/latitude, I want to implement a tile-based worldmap that gets it's data from the backend like { 1010, 1011, 1012 ... }. Thanks!

Comment: I am also looking for this answer!

Comment: +1 for a more up-to-date explanation of using non-lat/lng coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

A grid coordinate system could be made to bear close resemblance to a sector on a sphere with nearly square properties if it is made to occur just beneath the equator at zero degrees longitude. For all intents, over a 15 mile distance, the longitudinal lines will be very nearly parallel.

From here it would be a matter of scaling the grid coordinates to some $t$ seconds in width and height, and then set up a normalizing method that can feed Leaflet LatLng coordinates that it appears to need. Since you're staying in one hemisphere, with 0 degrees latitude/longitude at the northwest, your latitude will always be negative. Hope this gets you thinking...

Comment: To help in the scaling of your coordinates, the arc of  excursion from your starting point of longitude=0 is 15 km. Relative to half the earth's circumference it is, (1.5E1 / 2.0004E4 * pi) which gives us, 0.00235572335 rad. Since we know there are 6.48E5 seconds in PI radians, we can suss out how many seconds there are in the 15 kms. of the map; i.e.; 1.5E1 / 2.0004E4 * pi * 6.48E5.

Comment: That should be, 1.5E1 / 2.0004E4 * pi * 6.48E5 / pi. The latter rational is our dimensional analysis. pi/pi cancels the radian units, and seconds are left in the result.

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet 0.8-dev has advanced enough to permit completely custom coordinate systems, here is a example that works perfectly on the meter scale, with linear CRC, even with a scale widget:

https://gist.github.com/MarZab/7e3b1522ebc383f448a0

Comment: very interesting, but I can you use it? if I try to add this code and then create the 'map' with the meters CRS, I get only errors anothing is shown

Comment: ive updated the example to have everything that is needed for it to work