# Coordinates to Lat Long in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, coordinates, leaflet

I'm here because I'm trying to create a GTA V map with Leafletjs API. In deed, I've got my tiles that are ready. But the aim is to put markers on the map by using GTA V in-game coordinates. To achieve it, I need to convert the coordinates to LatLong but after many researches, I can't find a solution.

Example :
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886406/leaflet-js-with-a-non-real-world-map-coordinates

Comment: A more recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638887/leaflet-custom-coordinates-on-image/34640343#34640343

Answer (score 4):

Your coordinates are coming from different map projections. The Leaflet ones are most probably standard WGS 84 (SRID 4326). GTA V coordinates are obviously based on a different projection.

Coordinates can be transformed from one projection to anothers. But you need to know, which projection your coordinates are coming from, to do the math.
[Here](http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/) is an online converter provided with some common projections, and i tried your coordinates, but had no luck in coming close with these projections.

Comment: If you are downvoting, please leave a comment with a reason. I'm just trying to help.

Comment: The answer is correct, don't know who would downvote it.

Comment: First, it's 4326 and not 4236. Secondly, this does not address the OP's question. He knows the projection of the data (it's image coordinates in pixels for a game map) but this is not a real world projection and he won't find anything useful on the site you provide.

Comment: hmm wouldn't it work if you converted it to cartesian and then calculate the multiplier needed to convert between GTA V and map

e.g. multiplier = gtaXPosition / mapXPosition and then just do mapXPosition * multiplier to convert back to GTA V position

that would probably work if you wanted to do leaflet -> GTA V position and you knew the real in-game position

Comment: then just do gtaXPosition / multiplier to get leaflet map position or something like that

Answer (score 4):

I tried this:

```
var latlng = new L.latLng(-43.1731, 6.6906);
var point = L.Projection.Mercator.project(latlng);
console.log(point);
// o.Point {x: 744794.1851014761, y: -5309112.129212381}
```

It is not close to your GTA V coordinates, but I'm not sure it were just for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `L.latlng` function

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't solve my problem, I already look in the docs. There is no method for it. It's more a math problem that I have to solve.