# Leaflet custom coordinates on image

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I have an image which size is 8576x8576px, and I want to make the coordinates match 1:1. Also I want the coordinates 0,0 in the center of the image (now the center is -128,128). And I want to show the coordinates too.  I want to put a locate button for the user insert coordinates and then find them on the map.
Something like this: http://xero-hurtworld.com/map_steam.php
(I am using the same image but bigger). The tile size I made its 268px.

My code so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/ze62dte0/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      function init() {
        var mapMinZoom = 0;
        var mapMaxZoom = 3;
        var map = L.map('map', {
          maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
          minZoom: mapMinZoom,
          crs: L.CRS.Simple
        }).setView([0, 0], mapMaxZoom);



    window.latLngToPixels = function(latlng){
    return window.map.project([latlng.lat,latlng.lng], window.map.getMaxZoom());
    };
    window.pixelsToLatLng = function(x,y){
    return window.map.unproject([x,y], window.map.getMaxZoom());
    };

        var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
            map.unproject([0, 8576], mapMaxZoom),
            map.unproject([8576, 0], mapMaxZoom));

        map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
        L.tileLayer('{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
          minZoom: mapMinZoom, maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
          bounds: mapBounds,
          noWrap: true,
          tms: false
        }).addTo(map);

        L.marker([0, 0]).addTo(map).bindPopup("Zero");

        L.marker([-128, 128]).addTo(map).bindPopup("center");

        var popup = L.popup();

        <!-- Click pop-up>
        var popup = L.popup();

        function onMapClick(e) {
            popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked in " + e.latlng.toString ())
            .openOn(map);
        }

        map.on('click', onMapClick);

      }
    </script>
    <style>
      html, body, #map { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a CRS similar to `L.CRS.Simple` that places tile 0/0/0 (tile size 268px, which is 8576 / 2⁵) so that:

- Position `[0, 0]` is at the center of that tile.
- The entire world (i.e. entire tile 0/0/0) goes from position `[-8576/2, -8576/2]` to `[8576/2, 8576/2]`.

You would just need to adjust the `L.CRS.Simple` with the appropriate transformation, to account for this scale of 1/2⁵ = 1/32 (instead of just 1) and offset of 8576 * 1/32 / 2 = 268 / 2 = 134 (instead of 0.5).

```js
L.CRS.MySimple = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
  transformation: new L.Transformation(1 / 32, 134, -1 / 32, 134)
});

var map = L.map('map', {
  maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
  minZoom: mapMinZoom,
  crs: L.CRS.MySimple
}).setView([0, 0], mapMaxZoom);
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5SQqp7SP4nf8muPM5iso?p=preview (I used Plunker instead of jsfiddle because you provided a full page code with HTML, whereas jsfiddle expects you to split your HTML, CSS and JavaScript codes into separate blocks).

As for showing the coordinates and a "locate" button, it would be quite easy to implement so that it is similar to the example you mention. Feel free to open new questions if you need help.

In the above demo, I used [Leaflet.Coordinates plugin](https://github.com/MrMufflon/Leaflet.Coordinates) to implement quickly both functionalities (see the control on bottom left corner of the map; you have to start moving your mouse on the map for the coordinates to appear; click on that control to open the edition mode).

---

**EDIT:**

As for the Leaflet.Coordinates plugin, it wraps displayed coordinates longitude to stay within [-180; 180] degrees.

In your case where coordinates are not degrees, there is no point wrapping the longitude.

I think this is the cause for the discrepancy of coordinates between the click popup and the control.

Simply patch the plugin code to prevent wrapping:

```js
// Patch first to avoid longitude wrapping.
L.Control.Coordinates.include({
  _update: function(evt) {
    var pos = evt.latlng,
      opts = this.options;
    if (pos) {
      //pos = pos.wrap(); // Remove that instruction.
      this._currentPos = pos;
      this._inputY.value = L.NumberFormatter.round(pos.lat, opts.decimals, opts.decimalSeperator);
      this._inputX.value = L.NumberFormatter.round(pos.lng, opts.decimals, opts.decimalSeperator);
      this._label.innerHTML = this._createCoordinateLabel(pos);
    }
  }
});
```

Updated demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/M3Ru0xqn6AxAaSb4kIJU?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! The exact way I want it!

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for the feedback. Please can you consider upvoting and accepting this answer as well? This is the Stack Overflow system to thank people, even though of course a nice comment is highly appreciated as well! :-)

Comment: The only thing that I noticed is that there's a difference on the coordinates show by the bottom left controls and when I click the map. For example, if I put a marker on New York (1208, -1864) the coordinates shown on the controls are different. How I can make them look the same? Thanks again!

Comment: There is a `wrap` on the longitude inside Leaflet.Coordinates plugin. I forgot to patch it out for your case, let me edit the demo to show you.

Comment: Interesting, another quick question, The coordinates should not be equal to the Cartesian plane? Or like the example I metioned above, here: http://xero-hurtworld.com/map_steam.php

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If the display order bothers you (latitude / Y coordinate / ordinate / northing first, longitude / X coordinate / abscissa / easting second) in the control, you can change it using `useLatLngOrder: false` option when instantiating the control (see also Leaflet.Coordinates plugin page for details of options).

Comment: To match the cartesian plane, the coordinates should be:

   -x, +y | +x, +y
   --------|--------
   -x, -y  | +x, -y


Where X is the horizontal line and y is the vertical line. So X to the left should always be negative, and to the right positive, And Y above always positive and below negative.
After changing useLatLngOrder to false I can achieve that, but now it differs from the normal coordinates.

Comment: Yes that is what is done already. Only the display order is reversed: it currently shows y, x. Latitude is an ordinate (y), Longitude is an abscissa (x). Use `useLatLngOrder: false` option to get x, y. Updated demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/lYbCEYIMwotCV25YzKKX?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, and how can I reverse not only the display, but the coordinates too?
Because if I want to add a marker using the display as guidelines I will have to invert it.

Comment: I do not think this is easily doable (see related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484700/leaflet-latlngbounds-with-simpler-crs-projection), but as I show in that post, you can "patch" factories and functions so that you can use reverse order. You could try to ask a new question specifically on that, maybe other people will have some idea.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for the help. I think I will have to use this function to make it work. But at least, it works.
`function revertLat(x, y) {
  return [-y, x];
}`

Comment: Be careful, the `-y` was there because OP wanted ordinate increasing when going down, whereas in your case you want it the standard way (increasing going up). So you need `return [y, x]`.

Comment: Hey ghybs, I cannot make another question here yet, so could you help me with one last thing? I want to make the map fit the screem, I tried the bounds attribute but got no luck. I want it that you cannot scrool too far from its resolution.

Comment: See point 2 in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174868/how-to-hide-leaflet-base-map/174873#174873

Comment: Hey ghybs, sorry to bother you again, but I think there's something wrong.
My image have 8576x8576 and to ensure that I have draw lines making a retangle on the borders as you can see in my code, but the final image is smaller than it should be. So, what I am doing wrong? Your code looks right. Here is the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/6yx3PMrj8tYSihL3Slwi?p=preview
And here is how its rendering the final map: http://i.imgur.com/XFJOTfA.png

See that the map is smaller than it should be?

Comment: Have you specified your tile size as 268px? http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-tilesize

Comment: Thanks, forget that! Now I just need to make the return [y, x] function to work!