# Leaflet JS: Custom 2D projection that uses meters instead of lat,long

Tags: maps, leaflet, map-projections

I am working on a custom game map. This map is basically a raster image, overlayed with some paths and markers. I want to use [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to display the map.

What I am struggling with, is that Leaflet uses Latitude and Longitude to calculate positions, while it uses meters for distances (path lengths, radii of circles, etc).

This is very understandable when dealing with a spherical world like our Earth, but it complicates the custom map, which is flat a lot.

I would like to be able to specify the positions in the same unit as the distances.

Now, by default Leaflet uses a Spherical Mercator projection. According to the [Docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#iprojection), it is possible to define your own projections and coordinate reference systems, but I have been unable to do this thus far.

How would this be possible? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Paths `distanceTo()` and circles radii are computed in Leaflet version 0.x as if you were on a sphere, no matter the specified CRS. You would have to overwrite those methods, or use Leaflet 1.x (currently in beta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the simple coordinate reference system (`L.CRS.Simple`) included with Leaflet:

> A simple CRS that maps longitude and latitude into x and y directly. May be used for maps of flat surfaces (e.g. game maps).

You can define the CRS of your `L.Map` instead upon initialization like so:

```
new L.Map('myDiv', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
});
```

Some further elaboration: As @ghybs pointed out in the comment below and the comment to your question the default sperical mercator projection (`L.CRS.EPSG3857`) already works in meters. When you calculate the distance between two coordinates, Leaflet returns meters, example:

```
var startCoordinate = new L.LatLng(0, -1);
var endCoordinate = new L.LatLng(0, 1);

var distance = startCoordinate.distanceTo(endCoordinate);

console.log(distance);
```

The above will print `222638.98158654713` to your console which is the distance between those two coordinates in meters. Problem is that when using spherical projection, distance between two coordinates will become less the further you get from the equator which will become problematic when creating a flat gameworld. That's why you should use L.CRS.Simple, you won't have said problem.

Comment: The `L.CRS.Simple` would avoid the discrepancy between latitude and longitude, but it would not make coordinates as meters? For that you would also need to customize the CRS `transformation`, similarly to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638887/leaflet-custom-coordinates-on-image

Comment: I know @ghybs, but i thought i'de keep it simple because the poster will eventually run into problems because of the fact that length of degrees of latitude and longitude vary by latitude. Which at a large scale will eventually cause problems when creating a game world. But ok, i'll expand my answer too include this.