# Getting percentage-based or pixel based x & y coordinates from latlng

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm currently trying to get percentage or pixel coordinates from a latlng in leaflet.

Below is the script that creates the map and defines the tiles (taken from an app called 'maptiler')

```
    var mapMinZoom = 0;
    var mapMaxZoom = 3;
    var map = L.map('main-map', {
        maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
        minZoom: mapMinZoom,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).setView([0 0], mapMaxZoom);
    var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
        map.unproject([0, 1792], mapMaxZoom),
        map.unproject([2048, 0], mapMaxZoom));

    map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
    L.tileLayer('/_Content/leafletmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        minZoom: mapMinZoom, maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
        bounds: mapBounds,
        noWrap: true,
        tms: false
    }).addTo(map);
```

The main requirement here is for offline capability within a cordova application which is why we aren't using google maps API.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for Leaflet Map [Conversion Methods](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-conversion-methods):

- `latLngToLayerPoint(latlng)` to get the layer point relative to the **entire** map.
- `latLngToContainerPoint(latlng)` to get the point relative to the map container (`'main-map'` in your case).

Comment: I've generated an image of exactly 4096*4096 (values in code updated accordingly) filled in black to make sure that I'm clicking into the corners of the map, it seems that the top left in that function is returning `{x: 113, y: -65}` and bottom right is `{x: 366, y: 188}`

Comment: You are probably trying to have the x/y coordinates mapped to your 4096px-side image pixels? In that case, you would probably be interested in that post: [Leaflet custom coordinates on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638887/leaflet-custom-coordinates-on-image). If you use just `L.CRS.Simple`, your x/y coordinates will be mapped to pixels at zoom level 0.