# How to use Leaflet flyTo() with unproject() and GeoJSON data on a large raster image?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm building a story map with Leaflet using a large image sliced into tiles rather than 'real world' map data. I'm using this plugin: https://commenthol.github.io/leaflet-rastercoords/ and this repo: https://github.com/jackdougherty/leaflet-storymap

Loading my GeoJSON data and unprojecting the coordinates correctly plots them on my image map:

```
$.getJSON('map.geojson', function(data) {
  var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
  // correctly map the geojson coordinates on the image
    coordsToLatLng: function (coords) {
      return rc.unproject(coords)
  },
```

But when I get to onEachFeature, I hit the wall with map.flyTo(), which is calling geometry.coordinates from my JSON file, but not unprojecting them so flyTo() is interpreting them as geospatial coordinates way off the map:

```
map.flyTo([feature.geometry.coordinates[1], feature.geometry.coordinates[0] ], feature.properties['zoom']);
```

I tried passing the unprojected coordinates to variables and then to map.flyTo() and variations on nesting functions, such as map.flyTo.unproject(..., but no luck.

How do I pass my raster coordinates to flyTo()?

I'm not only new to Leaflet, but new to JavaScript. I hacked my way this far, but I'm stumped. I'm sure the solution is obvious. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you would probably just need to use `rc.unproject` to convert your coordinates into LatLng that you can pass to `flyTo`:

```js
map.flyTo(
  rc.unproject(feature.geometry.coordinates),
  feature.properties['zoom']
);
```

That being said, I must admit I do not exactly see the point of using leaflet-rastercoords plugin, since you can easily do the same by following the Leaflet tutorial ["Non-geographical maps"](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html).

```js
var yx = L.latLng;

var xy = function(x, y) {
  if (L.Util.isArray(x)) { // When doing xy([x, y]);
    return yx(x[1], x[0]);
  }
  return yx(y, x); // When doing xy(x, y);
};
```

With this, whenever you want to convert your "raster" coordinates into something usable by Leaflet, you would just use `xy(x, y)` with `x` being your horizontal value, and `y` your vertical one.

The added benefit is that many other things will become easily compatible.

Since you use tiles instead of a single image (that is stretched with `ImageOverlay` in the tutorial in order to fit the coordinates), you should modify the CRS transformation, so that at zoom 0, your tile `0/0/0` fits your entire coordinates. See also [Leaflet custom coordinates on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638887/leaflet-custom-coordinates-on-image)

I.e. in the case of leaflet-rastercoords example:

- Original raster image size: 3831 px width x 3101 px height
- Tiles size: 256 x 256 px
- Vertical "raster" coordinates are increasing while going down (whereas in the Leaflet tutorial, they increase going up, like latitude).
- Tile `0/0/0` actually covers *more* than the original image, as if the latter were 4096 x 4096 px (the rest is filled with white)

[image: Tile 0/0/0 from leaflet-rastercoords example]

Determination of the new CRS:

- Tile 0/0/0 should cover coordinates from top-left [0, 0] to bottom-right [4096, 4096] (i.e. 256 * 2^4 = 256 * 16 = 4096) => [transformation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#transformation) coefficients `a` and `c` should be `1/16`
- No offset needed => offsets `b` and `d` are `0`
- No reversion of `y` vertical coordinate => `c` is positive

Therefore the new CRS to be used would be:

```js
L.CRS.MySimple = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
  //                      coefficients: a      b    c     d
  transformation: new L.Transformation(1 / 16, 0, 1 / 16, 0)
});
```

Now your `flyTo` is very similar, but many other things are also compatible:

```js
map.flyTo(
  xy(feature.geometry.coordinates),
  feature.properties['zoom']
);
```

Demo adapted from leaflet-rastercoords example, and using an extra plugin to demonstrate compatibility: https://plnkr.co/edit/Gvei5I0S9yEo6fCYXPuy?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer. Simply using
`map.flyTo(
  rc.unproject(feature.geometry.coordinates),
  feature.properties['zoom']
);`
solved my issue. But I now see that I'm making it harder than it has to be using the rastercoords plugin.