# Changing the coordinate system on my leaflet map to custom (scale and 0,0 position)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm building a custom tilelayer map for a game. There is a current build-in coordinate system in the game and I'm looking to replicate it for ease of user access in finding coordinates and hooking into a database of locations.

I am trying to move the 0,0 of the CRS to a center location of the map however everything I have tried it is always in the top-left.

Is there a way to shift the tilelayer after it is added to the map?

Also, how would I go about changing the scale of the coordinates?

I have been trying to search quite a while for a solution but have come up with nothing that fits what I'm looking for. I've tried the https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html however unless I'm missing something, it's not helping me with this.

Here is an example: Blue lines are the current coordinate system, and red would be an example of where I would like it to be. [example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPlNB.jpg)

Here is where I initialize my map and tile layer.

```
    var map = new L.Map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple, 
        zoom: 3, 
        center:(hash), 
        minZoom: 2, 
        zoomControl: false, 
        noWrap: true, });
    var TopoLayer = L.tileLayer('map-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg').addTo(map);
```

Thank you, I feel like the solution is so simple that I am just skipping over it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638887/leaflet-custom-coordinates-on-image/34640343?r=SearchResults#34640343

Comment: If somebody wants to set [0,0] to the top left corner, using jladell's answer you can do this: var CRS = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, { transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, 1, 0), });

Answer (score 3):

```
    var factorx = 8
    var factory = 8

    L.CRS.pr = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
      projection: L.Projection.LonLat,
      transformation: new L.Transformation(factorx, 160, -factory, 52.9),

      scale: function(zoom) {
        return Math.pow(2, zoom);
      },

      zoom: function(scale) {
        return Math.log(scale) / Math.LN2;
      },

      distance: function(latlng1, latlng2) {
        var dx = latlng2.lng - latlng1.lng,
          dy = latlng2.lat - latlng1.lat;

        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      },
      infinite: true
    });
```

This seemed to do the trick :) Created a custom crs.